# Show all contributions from top donors

Tags: contributions, reports, searchkit, donations

I am trying to report on our top donors by year. I can see where to pull the top donor report, but that only aggregates the contributions per donor. That is part of what I need, but I am missing how to also show the individual donations made by each of the top donors.  If I put the Top Donors for a given year into a group, then run Find Contributions on that group, that gives me the data I need on the individual donations, but I can't figure out how to sort it to match the "Top Donor" order. Manually rearranging the rows in Excel seems a... not great workaround.  Would be so grateful for any guidance.

Comment: i think SearchKit will be your answer if you want more control over the columns and sorting options

Comment: Thanks for the guidance about SearchKit :)

Answer (score 3):

In Search Kit, try [this](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22display_name%22,%22SUM(Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.total_amount)%20AS%20SUM_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_total_amount%22,%22GROUP_CONCAT(Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.total_amount)%20AS%20GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_total_amount%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5B%22contact_type:name%22,%22%3D%22,%22Individual%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.receive_date%22,%22%3D%22,%22this.year%22%5D%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%22id%22%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Contribution%20AS%20Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01%22,%22INNER%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.contact_id%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)

Create the search as:

[image]

Note the 'Group By' contact ID, and 'total amount' field added twice - once as 'sum', once as 'list'.

You might want additional 'where' clauses for 'status = completed', 'type = donation' etc.

Then add a table and sort by '(Sum) Contact Contributions: Total Amount' Descending.  You might want to untick 'Use Pager' and then set Limit Results to eg 10.

[image]

Result:

[image]